# An uncaught Exception was encountered

Tags: codeigniter

Type: Exception

Message: Session: Configured save path 'C:\Windows\Temp' is not writable by the PHP process.

Comment: An off-topic Question was encountered. Type: No-MCVE / Message: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) not present in post.

Answer (score 4):

**Try to contact your host website about this error.**

It's just a problem of permission for files/folders.

```
Configured save path 'C:\Windows\Temp' is not writable by the PHP process
```

means permission is forbidden by server for CodeIgniter to save sessions in temp folder. If you can't do that yourself, then kindly ask your host to fix that for you.